# SharePoint 2010 Custom Events Calendar Add new Item hover not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I am have created a custom events list based on the OOTB Calendar via Visual Studio 2010.

I create my list def and package it up and deploy no issues.

I then create a new list based on my custom list definition.

All seems fine

But when I want to add an item from the calendar view there's no mousehover functionality anymore, for the add new event when hovering over a day item in the calendar view.

If I create a new events list based on the OOTB list definition I can get the add new event from the calendar view.

As far as I can tell all the relevant .js files are included on the page when viewing the source.

Is there a trick to get this working for a custom events list?

Comment: What kind of customization did you make in the custom events list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Type attribute is 106.

```
<ListTemplate
    Name="MyEvents"
    Type="106"
    BaseType="0"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    FolderCreation="FALSE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="340"
    DisplayName="Calendar (Custom)"
    Description=""
    Image="/_layouts/images/itevent.png"/>
```

This is a bug in my mind. In SharePoint 2007, I would always change the Type attribute so that it would not be confused with the out of the box List Definitions. However, with the introduction of the [XsltListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart.aspx) certain list types like events and discussions are only rendered properly if the Type matches the out of the box value.

Comment: Fantastic that worked. Thanks for that. I agree that this must be a bug. Do you know if there is a way to update the Type for already created lists? Thanks again! Pete

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It seems the only way would be to change the content database directly. But since that is unsupported, we deleted the old list and rebuilt it with the new definition.